# Java Applet Usage

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, jfilechooser, japplet

I was wondering how Java applets work in regards to accessing data on a users PC. For example I wish to grab a file on their PC and send it to the web server hosting my webpage (basically a simple file transfer client program). Can this be done using something like a JFileChooser dialog?

Comment: It can be done using pure HTML and a form based file input.  What does the applet bring to the mix for your use-case?  Do you already have the server set up to accept file uploads?

Comment: basically there are 3 interactions, there is me hosting the website and the applet, then there is the online storage facility, which is a provider with whom I have an account with, and then there is the client.
So basically, I am simply providing a nice and neat front end for them to interact with the storage facility. I will store files for user accounts and etc and they will need to be capable of downloading the files they need from the facility as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. You can always try and check it with minimal code (quick and dirty). [This](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/02/java-applet-file-uploader.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599018/java-applet-to-upload-a-file) and [this](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/index.html) might help.