# Encrypt File Upload content before uploading server side

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, servlets, applet

`FileUpload` control (GWT) will upload file on server using servlet. there is some security thread for that need to file encrypt on client side (In Browser) using certificate before uploading on server.

Requirement like:

```
-> Get content of file at client side
-> Encrypt the content at client side
-> Write that file with encrypted content on disk using servlet
```

so I was found some link
using [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers) & [applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599018/java-applet-to-upload-a-file)

if there is another solution and provide me correct way.

Actually upto now encryption handle at server side which may create security problem. certificate install on client machine so it is better to do all the encryption stuff on client end for security reason.

Comment: Using certificate? Why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: Yes,the requirement with certificate's public key encryption only.Let me update question.

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason.