# Post a file (and more values) into a http request in java

Tags: java, php, android, http

This is my code for making a HTTP post to an url

```
public static String post(String url, List<BasicNameValuePair> postvalues) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        if ( (postvalues==null) ){
            postvalues= new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        } 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postvalues, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return requestToString(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I'd like to add also a file to the post (not a byte[] with the final, just post the file into the PHP $_FILES field.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314249/upload-and-post-file-to-php-page

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In that question Albe is asking for uploading an image. I know how to upload an image and how to make a text but dont know how to combine both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to send a multi part request. This assumes that you can handle such a request on the server side:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
for(BasicNameValuePair postValue: postValues) {
    params.setParameter(postValue.getName(), postValue.getValue());
}

HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
post.setParams(params);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(myFile)));
post.setEntity(entity);
```

Alternatively to sending the name-value pairs as parameters, you can create a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` entity just like you are now, and add it to the multipart entity, as a separate part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It returns a null pointer exception when after that code I execute httpclient.execute(post) can you help me? The stacktrace says: java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)

at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)

at com.com.com.MytestActivity$1.onClick(MytestActivity.java:71)
 ...

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing your code. Is the URL being set in the `HttpPost` constructor?

Comment: Okey it was that stupid mistake. the file is now received correctly in the PHP but the other post field don't (at least as I usually read it: $name=$_POST['name']). Here is the java code:      BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
      params.setParameter("name", "1");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);      post.setParams(params);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();     entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(new File(NAME_OF_FILE)));      post.setEntity(entity);httpclient.execute(post);

Comment: Try out the `URLEncodedFormEntity` for the NameValuePairs then.

Comment: Okey calling a addPath("post_field","post_value") at the MultipartEntity finally worked. Thanks al lot for your info